# Need help, honeycomb emulator launch fails

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I run my application with Honeycomb emulator, it is showing the following error

```
[2013-01-25 17:56:54 - Demo] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Honeycomb'
[2013-01-25 17:57:07 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2013-01-25 17:57:07 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-01-25 17:57:08 - Demo] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2013-01-25 17:57:08 - Demo] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-01-25 17:58:24 - Demo] emulator-5556 disconnected! Cancelling 'android.demo.com.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

But other applications are running fine in other emulators like Gingerbread.

Did anyone face this problem? Please help me solve this.

Comment: try delete the emulator and then create a new emulator

Comment: Um... what earthly purpose could you have to support honeycomb? You're almost talking about the Windows Vista of Android, except a smaller percentage of its original users still have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this will help You
Go to the location C:\users\ur_pc_name\.android\cache and delete all the file